# Google Maps Directions to dropdown list of destinations from current position

Tags: jquery, google-maps, maps, directions, driving-directions

I have searched high and low for an answer on this. I am trying to have me current position shown on a google map, and have a drop down menu for a selection of locations, but the user can can only one from their current location.

The other option would be 2 dropdowns with the user current position included in each dropdown. I have seen many examples of a 2 list drown A-A, A-B, D-A etc but the user intitial position (via geolocate) is never included in either of the dropdowns.

I have this so far from a link:

http://thewebstorebyg.wordpress.com/2013/01/11/custom-directions-panel-with-google-maps-api-v3/

However i am unsure how to add the preset destinations to the A/B boxes as dropdowns. The "use my location" works fine so its just a question of adding a single or 2 dropdowns with the other locations as a choice.

Your help would be greatly appreciated